# yahoo finance API in R authentication issue

Tags: r, api, authentication, yahoo-finance

I am trying to use yahoo finance APIs. I created my account. I am trying to pull the data on R. I am getting status code 502

```
api_token <- "/X-API-KEY: myAPIkey"

base_url <- "https://yfapi.net/v11/finance/quoteSummary/"

info_url <- "?lang=en&region=US&modules=incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly"

accept_url <- "/accept: application/json"

full_url <- base::paste0(base_url, bist100_ticker[1], info_url, accept_url, api_token)

> full_url
[1] "https://yfapi.net/v11/finance/quoteSummary/AEFES.IS?lang=en&region=US&modules=incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly/accept: application/json/X-API-KEY: myAPIkey"
```

I am using the code above and the result is

```
api_call <- httr::GET(full_url)
> api_call$status_code
[1] 502
> 
> api_call$content
  [1] 3c 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0d 0a 3c 68 65 61 64 3e 3c 74 69 74 6c 65 3e 35 30 32 20
 [26] 42 61 64 20 47 61 74 65 77 61 79 3c 2f 74 69 74 6c 65 3e 3c 2f 68 65 61 64
 [51] 3e 0d 0a 3c 62 6f 64 79 3e 0d 0a 3c 63 65 6e 74 65 72 3e 3c 68 31 3e 35 30
 [76] 32 20 42 61 64 20 47 61 74 65 77 61 79 3c 2f 68 31 3e 3c 2f 63 65 6e 74 65
[101] 72 3e 0d 0a 3c 2f 62 6f 64 79 3e 0d 0a 3c 2f 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0d 0a
```

Any recommendations, please??

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, here it is if someone will have the same issue.

```
httr::GET(full_url,
                      add_headers('accept' = 'application/json',
                                  'X-API-KEY' = 'Your API Key is Here'))

Response [https://yfapi.net/v11/finance/quoteSummary/AEFES.IS?lang=en&region=US&modules=incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly]
  Date: 2021-12-30 15:04
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 6.08 kB
```